# Dropwizard example package compile-error

Tags: java, maven, locale, dropwizard

I'm totally new to Java and its tools, I would like to use Dropwizard framework.
I found an example found in its [repository](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example), however I could not run it.

As its said in the `README.md`, I need to run `mvn package`. However, as I understood, Maven tries to run integration tests but exception is thrown. The stack trace is like so:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.975 sec << FAILURE! - in com.example.helloworld.IntegrationTest
com.example.helloworld.IntegrationTest  Time elapsed: 5.974 sec  <<< ERROR!
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown data type: "İNT"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID İNT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)) [50004-192] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID İNT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:4079)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:3937)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5972)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4237)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:362)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1202)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:299)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:107)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:97)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:94)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:206)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:170)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:196)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:181)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.DbMigrateCommand.run(DbMigrateCommand.java:68)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.DbCommand.run(DbCommand.java:52)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.AbstractLiquibaseCommand.run(AbstractLiquibaseCommand.java:64)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
    at com.example.helloworld.IntegrationTest.migrateDb(IntegrationTest.java:38)
```

I think it has some issues with locale, because my operating system is **OS X 10.11 Turkish**, where we capitalize strings *'i'* to *'İ'*, not *'I'*.

I'm using *IntelliJ IDEA*, could you tell me how can I change current locale for the guy who is tested (I don't know it's *JVM* or *Maven* or something...)?

As it's requested, my `migrations.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="codahale">
        <createTable tableName="people">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="fullName" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="jobTitle" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Do you have a migration.xml file (It is the file used by liquidbase) ? If it is the case, can you put the source in your post ?

Comment: I think you are right, the problem come from your operating system and probably liquibase. What you can do is to generate manually the table. It doesn't solve your problem. You can change your OS local language but it sounds really inconvenient for this little problem. Otherwise you can check liquibase code on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have been caused by your locale settings of Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Simply change your locale to English by opening your terminal or console (for Windows) and running the following command.

`set JAVA_ARGS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US %JAVA_ARGS%`

To automate that, you might need to export the environment variable in your terminal startup script, something like `.bash_profile`.